# :after bug (chrome only)

Tags: css

I am building a website for a school project and I experiment a weird bug.

I use ::after and transform/transitions on my menu items. It works on all browsers but the tags in the right div have an animation on it **in chrome only**.

You can see it here : http://mbrillaud.fr/gamejutsu/
On hover on the menu, the tags (action, adventure etc ...) of the right div are "clipping".

The css for the menu :

```
.left a::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #282C34;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    -o-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 0.1s;
}
.left a:hover::after{
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Do someone have experienced this or have an idea ?
Thank you by advance for your help !

Comment: you don't have to put two '::', just use one like this `.left a:after`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have already tried this and nothing change. I just do it by convention.

Comment: @Jackson The proper syntax for pseudo-elements is `::`. However, for the pseudo-elements defined in CSS2.1, `:` is also allowed because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Chromium 42.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually isn't clipping on hover, it is always clipped and it is the backface-visibility showing. When you hover with css transitions chrome flickers the backface visibility. You can prevent the flicker by applying this:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

That won't prevent your tags from being clipped though. Change your line-height on .game-label-tags to be 1.6em and that will prevent the clipping and you will not need to apply the backface-visibility hack.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a background (gradient or img) and background-size.

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  background:linear-gradient(to top, black , black) no-repeat bottom center;
  background-size:0 2px;
  transition:0.1s;
}
a:hover {
  background-size:100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm gonna try this way on my other project.

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud some other idea then: colored border http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jdwgG , animation on fake border: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pKwby & http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC round or square via transition or animation : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bhxAL

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud , another way to cure a bug is to not provocate it . :)